# C++ - Why is the merge function reversing an array after recursively calling it?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort

**I have the following functions which implement a merge sort:**

The first function is the merge function and the second function is the mergeSort function.

As shown in the output, when the array [-3,8] goes inside the merge function it appears to be reversed to [8,-3] making the sort impossible.

- The input array is **int array[5] = {37, 45, 29, 8, -3};**
- The expected output would be: **Sorted Array: -3 8 29 27 45**

> ...
>
> Merging: ... ||arr1: 8 || arr2: -3 
>   **-------- NEW: -------- -3 8**
>
> Merging: ... ||arr1: 29 || **arr2: 8 -3**   -------- NEW: -------- 8 -3 29
>
> Merging: ... ||arr1: 37 45 || arr2: 29 8 -3   -------- NEW: --------
>   29 8 -3 37 45
>
> Sorted Array: 29 8 -3 37 45

**merge:**

```
int * ArraySort::merge(int arr1[], int arr1_size, int arr2[], int arr2_size){

    std::cout<<"\nMerging: ... ";
    int * new_array = new int [arr1_size+arr2_size];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    std::cout<<"||arr1: ";
    for(int i=0;i<arr1_size;i++)
        std::cout<<arr1[i]<<" ";

    std::cout<<"|| arr2: ";
    for(int i=0;i<arr2_size;i++)
        std::cout<<arr2[i]<<" ";


    while(i<arr1_size && j<arr2_size){
        if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
            new_array[k++] = arr1[i++];
        }
        else{
            new_array[k++] = arr2[j++];
        }
    }

    //    Clean up
    while(i<arr1_size){
        new_array[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
    while(j<arr2_size){
        new_array[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }

    std::cout<<"\n -------- NEW: -------- ";
    for(int i=0;i<arr1_size+arr2_size;i++)
        std::cout<<new_array[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<"\n";

    return new_array;
}
```

**mergeSort:**

```
int * ArraySort::mergeSort(int * arr, int size){
    std::cout<<"\n\nMerge Sort...\n";
    std::cout<<"ON: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    if(size == 1)
          return arr;

    int mid = size/2;
    std::cout<<"\nMid:"<<mid;

    int * left = new int[mid];
    int * right = new int [size-mid];

    std::cout<<"\nLEFT: ";
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++){
        left[i] = arr[i];
        std::cout<<left[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\nRIGHT: ";
    for(int i=mid;i<size;i++){
        right[i-mid] = arr[i];
        std::cout<<right[i-mid]<<" ";
    }
    mergeSort(left, mid);
    mergeSort(right, size-mid);

    return merge(left, mid, right, size-mid);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images! Can you copy that text into a code block? Also, what is your input, expected output and actual output? What debugging have you done and where did you find the problem to be?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I see more `new`s than `deletes`, you might want to fix that. Best fix would be to use `std::vector`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @scohe001thank you for the advise. I applied your advise to the question. The problem happens when array [-3,8] is about to merge array [29].Array [-3,8] is sent as [8,-3] which results in an unsuccessful merge.

Comment: The question as been solved. Thanks to all. The fix was to do:                                      left = mergeSort(left, mid);  right = mergeSort(right, size-mid);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mergeSort function returns int * which is ignored in recursion mode.
When you call mergeSort in same function, the return values are getting lost and the new merged arrays are never obtained for the next comparison.

replace these tow lines to fix the bug in the mergeSort function.

```
/* the problem is here, when the return values are ignored 
       the arrays are getting sorted but never actually updated */
    left = mergeSort(left, mid);
    right = mergeSort(right, size-mid);
```

The whole function

```
int * ArraySort::mergeSort(int * arr, int size){
    std::cout<<"\n\nMerge Sort...\n";
    std::cout<<"ON: ";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    if(size == 1)
          return arr;

    int mid = size/2;
    std::cout<<"\nMid:"<<mid;

    int * left = new int[mid];
    int * right = new int [size-mid];

    std::cout<<"\nLEFT: ";
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++){
        left[i] = arr[i];
        std::cout<<left[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\nRIGHT: ";
    for(int i=mid;i<size;i++){
        right[i-mid] = arr[i];
        std::cout<<right[i-mid]<<" ";
    }
    /* the problem is here, when the return values are ignored 
       the arrays are getting sorted but never actually updated */
    left = mergeSort(left, mid);
    right = mergeSort(right, size-mid);

    return merge(left, mid, right, size-mid);
}
```

output

> Merge Sort...
>   ON: -3
>   Merging: ... ||arr1: 8 || arr2: -3
>   -------- NEW: -------- -3 8
>
> Merging: ... ||arr1: 29 || arr2: -3 8
>   -------- NEW: -------- -3 8 29
>
> Merging: ... ||arr1: 37 45 || arr2: -3 8 29
>   -------- NEW: -------- -3 8 29 37 45

Comment: Thank you so much Bhaumik! That fixed everything! I appreciate your response ! Big help!